# How to best store a complex object of MQTT messages in a React App State?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, mqtt

I want to develop a React App with TypeScript, which can store and send MQTT data.

There are a lot of (hundreds) MQTT messages like:
`config.laser.enable == "true"`, `config.system.value == "23"` or `config.user.password == "foobar"`.

So I end up with an object like:

```
{
   "config.laser.enable": true,
   "config.system.value": 23,
   "config.user.password": "foobar",
   ...
}
```

Each of my visual components will use only a small subset of these topics.

My first approach was to create a MQTT client for each component and subscribe to their individual topics, but this seems to be a lot of overhead. So I believe it would be better to have only one MQTT client, which subscribes to everything and stores the message data in a global state.
So my question is: How can I (or shouldn't I?) store complex data (an object) in a global state in React and making sure that only the components redraw when their specific subset of the global state has changed. Can I use **React Redux** for this?

Can you give me an example on how to do this?

I am new to React, so please forgive if this is trivial.

Comment: Make a whitelist of what you want and ignore others (don't set them in state at all) ?

Comment: It is too many objects needed in many different components. I will need a global state.

Answer (score 3):

React context should be a good fit for such tasks. It is also the backbone for the Redux library.
Here is an excerpt from the React [manual](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html):

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components

A proof-of-concept example of using React context:

```
const GlobalMessages = React.createContext({});

function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalMessages.Provider value={/* pass the messages here */}>
      <SomeComponent/>
      <RandomContainer/>
    </GlobalMessages.Provider>;
  )
}

function SomeComponent() {

  // All instances of SomeComponent nested at any level inside
  // GlobalMessages.Provider will now have access to its value.
  let msgContext = useContext(GlobalMessages);

  let message = msgContext.messageTypeA; // Your "selector"

  return <Textbox value={message} />;
}
```

Note that in the above example all components that use the `GlobalMessages.Provider` context will rerender when its `value` prop changes and this might have some performance implications.

Fortunately, React component rerenders are usually quite cheap due to [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html). This means most renders will never touch the real DOM at all. If you are sure you have an expensive component that you would like to avoid rerendering - you can [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) it like this:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  let msgContext = useContext(GlobalMessages);
  let message = msgContext.messageTypeA; // Your "selector"

  return useMemo(() => {
    // The rest of your rendering logic
    return <ExpensiveComponent value={message} />;
  }, [message])
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This global context and memoization works astonishingly well.